# Were Kanjiklub always intended to be a human group?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, behind-the-scenes

In *The Force Awakens*, Han refers to the members of Kanjiclub as "little freaks." This insult doesn't really make sense, given how they ultimately appear in the film.

[image]

Were they at one point in the film's production intended to be aliens?

Comment: I don't have an answer to the question of the production's intention, but for just the question of word use, well, human-folk have been using "freak" to insult human-folk for a very long time

Comment: I'm unsure why freak has to mean visually appalling, or alien. It could simply be because of their typically unusual behaviour.

Comment: @Edlothiad Describing them as "little" is what's confusing me more.

Comment: Yes, I don't think I remember any "little" persons running around the space ship, only more or less normal sized persons.